# Why is this SQL INSERT failing without raising and exception?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, sql-insert

I have a problem with an INSERT into a table on Azure SQL which is failing - returning a -1 on rows affected using the `ExecuteNonQuery` command.

The Table looks like this:

[image: URLS Table]

and the code is like this:

```
private void SaveUrls(ArrayList alUrls)
{
    int rows = 0;
    this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

    foreach (string url in alUrls)
    {
        try
        {
            // INSERT INTO URLS (UrlHash,URLPath,DiscoveryDate,IsInProcessingQueue) VALUES('83B2DE6A8247D2F0C1F674DA0DC4E173230C541542D0A4852A8F83AC8A874D43E2A9335B3A505A50DBC735592D792E9A2564FF556EB3286C7F974A0EDE995F46','http://google.com/blog-entry-4835.html', getutcdate(), False)
            // INSERT INTO URLS (UrlHash,URLPath,DiscoveryDate,DiscoveredById,IsInProcessingQueue) VALUES('83B2DE6A8247D2F0C1F674DA0DC4E173230C541542D0A4852A8F83AC8A874D43E2A9335B3A505A50DBC735592D792E9A2564FF556EB3286C7F974A0EDE995F46','http://google.com/blog-entry-4835.html', getutcdate(), 1006, False)
            // INSERT INTO [dbo].[URLS] ([UrlId], [UrlHash], [URLPath], [DiscoveryDate], [DiscoveredById], [ProcessedDate], [ProcessedById], [IsInProcessingQueue], [JoinedProcessingQueueDate]) VALUES (1, N'83B2DE6A8247D2F0C1F674DA0DC4E173230C541542D0A4852A8F83AC8A874D43E2A9335B3A505A50DBC735592D792E9A2564FF556EB3286C7F974A0EDE995F46', N'http://google.com/blog-entry-4835.html', N'2015-03-05 22:44:18', 1006, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL)
            // INSERT INTO URLS ([UrlId], [UrlHash], [URLPath], [DiscoveryDate], [DiscoveredById], [ProcessedDate], [ProcessedById], [IsInProcessingQueue], [JoinedProcessingQueueDate]) VALUES(N'83B2DE6A8247D2F0C1F674DA0DC4E173230C541542D0A4852A8F83AC8A874D43E2A9335B3A505A50DBC735592D792E9A2564FF556EB3286C7F974A0EDE995F46',N'http://google.com/blog-entry-4835.html',N'getutcdate()', 1006, ,,False,)
            // INSERT INTO URLS ([UrlId], [UrlHash], [URLPath], [DiscoveryDate], [DiscoveredById], [ProcessedDate], [ProcessedById], [IsInProcessingQueue], [JoinedProcessingQueueDate]) VALUES(N'83B2DE6A8247D2F0C1F674DA0DC4E173230C541542D0A4852A8F83AC8A874D43E2A9335B3A505A50DBC735592D792E9A2564FF556EB3286C7F974A0EDE995F46',N'http://google.com/blog-entry-4835.html',N'getutcdate()', 1006, '','',False,'')

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO URLS ([UrlId], [UrlHash], [URLPath], [DiscoveryDate], [DiscoveredById], [ProcessedDate], [ProcessedById], [IsInProcessingQueue], [JoinedProcessingQueueDate]) VALUES(N'" + HashPassword(url) + "',N'" + url + "',N'getutcdate()', 1006, '" + null+ "','" + null + "'," + false + ",'" + null + "')");
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.Connection = con;

            rows += command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException sqle)
        {
            Log("SQL ERROR: SaveUrls " + sqle.Message);
        }

        Application.DoEvents();
    }

    this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;

    Log("Seeded URLS Table with " + rows.ToString("N0") + " rows");

    alUrls.Clear();           
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is how the tables are related:

[image: Diagram]

**UPDATE 2:**

1. There is no exception generated
2. Even with the UrlId removed the insert fails.

Comment: What is the exception message _exactly_?

Comment: Please [protect your code from SQL injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx).

Comment: Do your HashPassword method return strings with the quote character on it?

Comment: It looks to me like you're missing an insert value. There's nine columns specified for insert and only 8 values, if I'm reading this right. Also, please use Parameters (see BCdotWEB's link), which will make it a lot easier to debug your code and protect you from injection.

Comment: `[UrlId]` is probably autogenerated - just remove it from `INSERT`.

Comment: As I said - NO Exception message is generated I just get  a -1 for rows affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer turns out that the URLHash column of varchar(128) was too small to hold a string of 128 characters!

I have no idea how that works but after removing the constraints and changing the varchar(128) to nvarchar(256) (not sure why it was varchar anyway) I reinstated the constraints and hey presto it works.

Answer (score 3):

Your INSERT statement specifies the `UrlId` field, but the first value you supply is the hash.

```
INSERT INTO URLS ([UrlId], [UrlHash], [URLPath]...
```

should be

```
INSERT INTO URLS ([UrlHash], [URLPath]...
```

Also, as others have said in the comments, use parameters instead of building your SQL string up!